# Cannot access PHPMyAdmin after installing Django

Tags: python, phpmyadmin, django

I usually access phpMyAdmin on my server by going to `www.mysite.com/phpMyAdmin`, however after I've installed Django, when I go to the mentioned address, I get the Django `It worked` page.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by placing the following in httpd.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /full/path/to/phpmyadmin/
<Directory /full/path/to/phpmyadmin>
   Options -Indexes
   ...etc...
</Directory>
```